# AngularJS ng-click on li icon

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code

```
<div  ng-repeat="names in mitypes  = (mitype | filter:{parentid:0}:true)"> 

    <li ng-click="newObject[names.id]=!newObject[names.id]">
      <label ng-click="selectedlist[names.id]=!selectedlist[names.id]">{{names.id}}  </label>
    </li>

    </div>
   </div>
```

Its tree of ul li elements. So i want to have 2 any event of click:
1. Click li ng-click for open/close tree branch
2. Click label ng-click for select tree node

li element have css style:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}
li.closed
{
  background-image: url(1.png);
}
li.opend
{
  background-image: url(2.png);
}
```

I want click on png image for open/close and label for select node.
Now, when you click on any part of the "li" both variables change their meaning.

How can I split these events?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard event propagation behavior in browsers.

Try `$event.stopPropagation` on your `<label>`:

```
<label ng-click="selectedlist[names.id]=!selectedlist[names.id]; $event.stopPropagation()">{{names.id}}  </label>
```

If you want want to open when clicking left at the number, add padding-left to `<li>`:

```
li {
 list-style-type: none; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left center;
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius:5px;
 background-color:lightblue;
 padding-left: 30px; //add padding
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/yae9hyGm5ZHZdcBvvEd5?p=preview)

Comment: thx a lot. so my label padding-left: 30px; but not i have only 1 click on label. how i can have 2nd click on li?

Comment: @user3449258: sorry, I don't understand. Can you elaborate ? Is this what you want: `How can I split these events?`

Comment: @user3449258: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want to make it easy to click the `<li>`, make your `<li>` bigger or add padding to it.

Comment: sorry, my english is very bad =(

Comment: @user3449258: I looked at your plunk. But clicking at the label and clicking at the left padding trigger the same function because it's the same element. Move your `padding-left: 30px;` to `li` would work http://plnkr.co/edit/yae9hyGm5ZHZdcBvvEd5?p=preview