# AngularJS ng-click not working in <li> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm making a pagination list image using `AngularJS`. `ng-click` doesn't work when I use it in `<li>` tag or even on `<a>` tag in it. But it's working fine in `<button>` tag.

```
<div  ng-controller="sampleCtrl" ng-app="myApp" data-ng-init="currentpage=1">
            <h2>{{currentpage}}</h2>
        <ul>
             <li data-ng-repeat="image in images[currentpage-1]">
                <img src='{{ image.img }}' width="150px" height="88px"/>
             </li>
        </ul>


    <ul class="pagination">
        <li data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" title="Page {{i}}">
            <a href="#" data-ng-click="currentpage = currentpage + 1">{{i}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button data-ng-click="currentpage = currentpage + 1">Click me!</button>

</div>
```

Anyone knows what's the problem?

BTW, I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575895/angularjs-ng-click-on-li-icon), but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each repeated element. And when you're doing `currentpage = currentpage + 1`, you're most probably creating a new variable inside a child scope.

Check your scopes. The solutions is usually something as simple as `$parent.currentpage = $parent.currentpage + 1` (to address the `currentpage` variable in the parent scope, the `sampleCtrl` scope) if you don't want to rewrite the whole thing.

Another solution would be creating a function to increase the page number, that way you won't be creating any new child scope variables, but would inherit the increase function from the controller:

```
<a href="#" data-ng-click="increasePage()">{{i}}</a>
```

And in your controller something like this:

```
$scope.increasePage = function() {
     currentpage++;
}
```

Comment: Because the button is outside of `ng-repeat`.