# Angular: ng-click and <li> items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the fabulous [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for Angular but am having difficulty getting an onclick event raised.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_cargo.png'/> CARGO</a></li>
    <li><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_commercial.png'/> COMMJ</a></li>
    <li><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_executive.png'/> EXECJ</a></li>
    <li><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_travel.png'/> TVL</a></li>
</ul>
{{ currentDepartment }}
```

I've tried every combination: putting the ng-click="behaviour()" variously inside the li, the a and the img, but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

(ideally I'd just like to change the value of a scope variable but I'm thinking calling a behaviour to do the work is better practice)

This question is not the same as suggested above. The other question is to do with scope, whereas I would be happy just to be able to execute an alert(); from one of my li's.

Comment: Hi! Can you share a jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: `<a href="/something">` not work?

Comment: Please show an example of something that you've tried and the code for `behaviour()`. It's impossible to say what you're doing wrong without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-click not working in <li> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216459/angularjs-ng-click-not-working-in-li-tag)

Comment: Hmm...I have lots of images locally and links and stuff, not sure that would be straightforward. I'll give it a go though.

Comment: @Juhuna, I've not even got as far as calling a behaviour.  A simple alert would be ok for the moment.

Comment: You need to show a simple example that duplicates the issue, or all we can do is guess at what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a ng-click="behaviour()"><img src='/Content/Images/dept_cargo.png'/> CARGO</a></li>
```

Make sure you have `$scope.behaviour = function() {}` defined inside of the controller for that code snippet.

Comment: Are you sure its scoped correctly?  Seeing other content from the same controller working as expected?

Comment: You were right. A scope problem indeed. Now fixed and working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must have an issue in the js code where you set up the controller but if you set it up right, your html should look like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-click="behaviour()"><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_cargo.png'/> CARGO</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="behaviour()"><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_commercial.png'/> COMMJ</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="behaviour()"><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_executive.png'/> EXECJ</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="behaviour()"><a><img src='/Content/Images/dept_travel.png'/> TVL</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in your js:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.behaviour = function () {
       alert('asd');
    };
}
```

and here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/97u2jp6d/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more than this:

HTML

```
 <ul>
  <li ng-click="doSomething()">item 1</li>
  <li ng-click="doSomething()">item 2</li>
  <li ng-click="doSomething()">item 3</li>
  <li ng-click="doSomething()">item 4</li>
  <li ng-click="doSomething()">item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
$scope.doSomething = function () {
console.log('doing something');
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/52C2daC9jugCOOaNBDvP